# Wildcard certificate generated for local CA do not work for the subdomains

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, sub-domain

I have created `Makefile` to simplify generation certificates for local development:

```
DOMAIN   ?= localhost
NAME     ?= ${DOMAIN}

CAKEY    ?= CAkey.key
CACERT   ?= CAcert.pem

SIGN_REQ ?= ${NAME}.csr
CERT     ?= ${NAME}.crt
PEM      ?= ${NAME}.pem
KEY      ?= ${NAME}.key

CA = "/C=US/ST=NY/O=/localityName=City/CN=Hauleth/emailAddress="

SUBJECT = "/CN=*.${DOMAIN}"

verify: ${PEM} ${CACERT}
    openssl version
    openssl x509 -noout -text -in "$<"
    openssl verify -verify_hostname ${DOMAIN} -CAfile ${CACERT} $<
    openssl verify -verify_hostname test.${DOMAIN} -CAfile ${CACERT} $<

clean:
    $(RM) -f "${CERT}" "${SIGN_REQ}" "${PEM}" "${KEY}"

${CAKEY}:
    openssl genrsa -out "$@" 2048

${CACERT}: ${CAKEY}
    openssl req -subj ${CA} -x509 -new -nodes -key "$<" -sha256 -days 1825 -out "$@"

installCA: ${CACERT}
    security import "$<"
    security add-trusted-cert "$<"

cleanCA:
    security remove-trusted-cert "${CACERT}"
    $(RM) -f "${CACERT}" "${CAKEY}"

config.conf:
    echo 'subjectAltName=$${ENV::SAN}' > "$@"

${KEY}:
    openssl genrsa -out "$@" 2048

${SIGN_REQ}: ${KEY}
    openssl req -new -sha256 -subj $(SUBJECT) -key "$<" -out "$@" \
        -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:${DOMAIN},DNS:*.${DOMAIN}"

${CERT}: ${SIGN_REQ} ${CACERT} ${CAKEY} config.conf
    SAN="DNS:${DOMAIN},DNS:*.${DOMAIN}" \
        openssl x509 -req -out "$@" -in ${SIGN_REQ} \
        -CA ${CACERT} -CAkey ${CAKEY} -CAcreateserial \
        -days 1825 -sha256 \
        -extfile config.conf

${PEM}: ${CERT} ${KEY}
    cat ${CERT} ${KEY} > "$@"

.PHONY: clean verify install installCA cleanCA
```

Which in short creates local CA certificate and key and then generate certificate signed by that CA.

It works when I want to connect to the server with the certificate via `localhost`, but when I try `test.localhost` then it states that the certificate do not match.

```
$ openssl verify -verify_hostname test.localhost -CAfile CAcert.pem localhost.pem
CN = *.localhost
error 62 at 0 depth lookup: Hostname mismatch
error localhost.pem: verification failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The checking of the hostname is done in [X509_check_host](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/X509_check_host.html). This function calls the internal function [valid_star](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509v3/v3_utl.c#L694) to make sure that the given wildcard in CN or SAN can actually be used.

This function checks that wildcard-CN/SAN  like  `*` or `*.com` are treated as invalid since they are too broad. `*.example.com` is instead acceptable. Thus check is done by counting the dots inside the name and make sure that at least two dots are in there:

```
/*
 * The final label must not end in a hyphen or ".", and
 * there must be at least two dots after the star.
 */
if ((state & (LABEL_START | LABEL_HYPHEN)) != 0 || dots < 2)
    return NULL;
```

Based on this `*.localhost` is treated as a too broad wildcard specification and will not be used for the wildcard match. If you instead run your Makefile with `DOMAIN=example.com` it should be fine since this will result in a name of `*.example.com` which has two dots.

Comment: It seems to work, however I am sure that I had setup where I could use wildcard on TLD. With the rise of company owned TLDs it would be IMHO reasonable to allow wildcards on that as well.

Comment: @Hauleth: Even with company owned TLD `*.domain` should not be possible. See also [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) and their relation to wildcard certificates. Also, at least some major browsers don't allow this either.